# Facebook link not showing thumbnail

Tags: php, html, facebook, silverstripe

I just cant seem to get facebook to use thumbnails when linking to my blog!

I have tried adding a metatag for the thumbnail and specified the url to stop 301 circular redirect problems but its still not working.

My blog is powered by Silverstripe. Every other page works fine when linking to it, just not the blog page.

Anyone else had the same problem and found a solution?

www.wearecollective.co.nz/blog or http://wearecollective.co.nz/blog/?url=/blog

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try to assign image url through open graph. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding the og:image meta tag explicitly as suggested by this...

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwearecollective.co.nz%2Fblog%2F%3Furl%3D%2Fblog